# Is there a copy of Troitsky's analysis of KNN vs. KP online anywhere?

Tags: analysis, endgame, theory, books, knight-endgame

This is almost certainly public domain material by now (I believe it originates in a 1906 article), but I'm happy to buy it with or without *Collection of Chess Studies* if I can get it as a digital download somewhere.

Nunn defers to the original analysis because of how accurate it was. The derivative material on this endgame from other authors leaves too much unanswered for a more complete understanding (the original analysis contains dozens of pages).

Comment: http://www.chesszone.org/lib/books/troizky-360/troizky-360.zip has a download of the 360 Briliant and Instructive Endgames

Answer (score 4):

Troitsky's analysis of the endgame K+NN v K+P was published in the German magazine *Deutsche Schachzeitung* in 19 installments between 1906 and 1910. They all can be read online. I am not aware of an English translation. A Russian book featuring his full analysis was published during Troitsky's lifetime. Apart from that, I don't know of any other source.

Permalinks of the five relevant *Deutsche Schachzeitung* volumes follow below. In case that I missed an installment, serve yourself in the TOC at the beginning of each volume.

To access the full text you need to connect from a US IP address. If you are located elsewhere, use a VPN and set the USA as your country of origin.

- Deutsche Schachzeitung 1906 (vol. 61)
  permalink: https://hdl.handle.net/2027/njp.32101072325978
  pages 129, 161. 193, 257
- Deutsche Schachzeitung 1907 (vol. 62)
  permalink: https://hdl.handle.net/2027/njp.32101072325960
  pages 1, 97, 161, 225
- Deutsche Schachzeitung 1908 (vol. 63)
  permalink: https://hdl.handle.net/2027/uc1.a0002788768
  pages 1, 101, 197, 293
- Deutsche Schachzeitung 1909 (vol. 64)
  permalink: https://hdl.handle.net/2027/njp.32101072325945
  pages 33, 97, 161, 225, 321
- Deutsche Schachzeitung 1910 (vol. 65)
  permalink: https://hdl.handle.net/2027/njp.32101072325937
  pages 65, 129